# Using Appium and Espresso together a bad idea?

Tags: android, appium, android-espresso, functional-testing, test-pyramid

I'm a fanboy of Test-pyramid application in software development and want the same to be applied in Mobile software development as well.

For this, I'm desiring to leverage both Appium (for functional tests) and Espresso (for Integration Tests), and have the following questions:
The structure of my tests in Android Studio with Gradle has only 2 folders: `app/src/test` and `app/src/androidTest`.
The former test is meant for writing Unit tests with JUnit. The later for functional tests; and I'm using espresso tests for integration-testing making use of the latter directory.

I know I can create a separate project for Appium and write functional tests. But prefer to have those as part of the project in separate test source directory, so that it can be run at different intervals in my CI pipeline. How do I go about doing this? Is it possible to create another source test directory like `app/src/functionalTest`? Pointers to sample projects in github or resources is well appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious why not just use Espresso for both?

Comment: @tim, because you can't navigate between activities like how a functional tests are written.